# why does spark streaming query fail java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 minutes]

Tags: spark-streaming, azure-eventhub, watermark

I have a streaming query streaming data from Azure Eventhubs to ADLS every 5 seconds and the same streaming query is watermark for 1 hour window with 5 minute water mark delay.

Code:

```
    val rawStreamQuery = messages.writeStream.format("delta")
    .option("checkpointLocation", BASE_LOC + "checkpoint/" + RAW_SCHEMA_NAME + "/" + RAW_TASK_TABLE)
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(RAW_STREAM_TRIGGER_INTERVAL))
    .table(RAW_SCHEMA_NAME + "." + RAW_TASK_TABLE)

    rawStreamQuery.withWatermark(watermarkTimeStamp, STREAM_WATERMARK) //5 minutes 
      .groupBy(window(col(watermarkTimeStamp), STREAM_WINDOW).as("window")) //1 hour        
      .count()
      .select(
        lit(commonDataObj.getFeedName).as("feed_name")
        , lit(commonDataObj.getStage).as("stage_name")
        , col("count").as("record_count")
        , col("window").getField("start").as("start_ts")
        , col("window").getField("end").as("end_ts")
      )
```

Getting the below error.

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 minutes]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.$anonfun$result$1(package.scala:220)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:57)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.createReceiver(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.recreateReceiver(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.checkCursor(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:169)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.org$apache$spark$eventhubs$client$CachedEventHubsReceiver$$receive(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver$.receive(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.rdd.EventHubsRDD.compute(EventHubsRDD.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:640)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:643)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for this? I'm having similar issues

Comment: no..something to do with spark lock.wait property i guess.. please let me know if you are able to fix the same.

Comment: We have that set to 30 seconds already.. in addition we now also disabled spark preemption by setting `spark.databricks.preemption.enabled false` because of some comments [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/582). However we only encounter this issue irregularly; last time our streaming job ran for 130 hours before the timeout happened so we'll have to see if this helps

Comment: same here..it is happening irregularly..will let you know if anything comes up..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure since you don't show your full code, you talk about reading a stream from eventhubs but i only see your write stream to delta, anyways i used to have this problem when the input stream from eventhubs didn't send events for some time, it seems the underlying library has a timeout exception configured when the stream doesn't receive data, you could try sending continuos data and check if the error persists.